# Solving the matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

How can I solve the matrix equation of the form

$$
\mathbf{SXK} + \mathbf{X} = \mathbf{Y}
$$

Here $\mathbf{S}$ and $\mathbf{K}$ are symmetric matrices, in addition $\mathbf{K}$ is a sparse symmetric matrix.  $X$ is the variable. Though $\mathbf{S}$ and $\mathbf{K}$ are symmetric, it is not invertible in general and $\mathbf{X}$ is not symmetric. Is it possible to find a closed-form solution for $\mathbf{X}$ ?. Is there any relevant literature study about solving such equations ?

Comment: Are all square matrices? $S,K$ are invertible?

Comment: @Exodd, S and K are not invertible in general.  though S and K are symmetric, X is not symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symmetry of $S$ and $K$ allow for you to write them as diagonalized matrices. Suppose we have

$$S=PDP^{-1},\;\;\;\;K=QCQ^{-1}$$

for diagonal matrices $C$ and $D$. We also may write $X$ as

$$X=PP^{-1}XQQ^{-1}$$

which gives us

$$PDP^{-1}XQCQ^{-1}+PP^{-1}XQQ^{-1}=Y$$

Letting $Z=P^{-1}XQ$, we have

$$PDZCQ^{-1}+PQ^{-1}Z=Y$$

or

$$DZC+Z=P^{-1}YQ$$

The matrix $DZC$ is the matrix $Z$ with rows scaled by elements of $D$ and columns scaled by elements of $C$. This leads to a system of equations that look like

$$[D]_i[Z]_{ij}[C]_j+[Z]_{ij}=[P^{-1}YQ]_{ij}$$

The existence and uniqueness of a solution can now be seen, as it is dependent upon the value of $[D]_i[C]_j$. Provided that this is not $-1$, then

$$[Z]_{ij}=\frac{[P^{-1}YQ]_{ij}}{[D]_i[C]_j+1}$$

The matrix $X$ may the be recovered by $X=PZQ^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

This equation is similar to the [discrete Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation) and can be solved in a similar way. Using the equality 
$$ \operatorname{vec}(ABC)=(C^{T} \otimes A)\operatorname{vec}(B) $$
one obtains the system of linear equations
$$
\left( K^T \otimes S+I_{n^2} \right)\operatorname{vec}(X)=\operatorname{vec}(Y).
$$